# How do I use Circuit Lab to show me Voltage and current information on this circuit?

Tags: led, resistors, circuit-analysis, circuitlab

I have a bunch of red LEDs, I don't have their data sheet and I am trying to figure out a safe resistor to use to lower the current across them safely.

My current setup is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAa0b7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I figured a 100 Ohm resistor and 68 ohm resistor in series because, assuming a forward voltage of the led of 3 volts, and a desired current of 20mA (which I assume is ok?) I get:

```
R=V/I
R=3.3/0.02
R=165 Ohms.
```

So, I pop that into the circuit lab as shown below, click run, then click DC simulation, but then it just throws an error saying : `"unable to get solution"`

How do I use this tool to allow me to inspect various values at various points in the circuit? Have I got this wrong somehow?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5hsnk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Add a GND to the schematic so the simulator has a zero volt reference.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Add nodes at the points you want to monitor. Rename them to suit your purposes. Run the DC solver.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Click each named node to add it to the DC solver tab.*

[image]

*Figure 4. Click on a wire to monitor the current.*

Comment: Note with Vled=2.1V@25mA with 3 LEDs in series =6.3V (for this LED model values) , no series R is needed. and with 2.1-1.8= 0.3V /25mA the ESR is 12 Ohms within the xx% tolerance of my model of 15 Ohms which depends on supplier binning and quality. Thanks @transistor for validating my experience and showing the details of CircuitLab

Answer (score 0):

If 6.3V is stable, you can use AlInGaAs RED LED x3 in series with NO resistors safely.

Then use as many 3S strings in parallel as your regulated PS can support.

If Vout is 6.5 or more then add 1Ohm per 100mV per 100mA of LED current. imagine each 5mm Red LED as a 1.8V diode with 15 Ohms inside, give or take xx%

- edit (typo , 1.8 not 2.8)

> - To answer your (explicit) question for single point voltages, add gnd , which will work, then to see current, select component by name.
> - for better help on volt/amp meter readings read https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/the-basics/#volt_and_ammeter

Comment: Tony, I think that's an answer to another question somewhere in cyberspace. Read the title and his final paragraph again.

Comment: you are probably right but then sometimes the best answer is a better solution not asked for. I gave a better model too for Ohmslaw manual trivial calculations

Comment: My red LEDs are around 1.8 volts, and common LEDs have a maximum current rating of 20 mA or so - I usually aim for about 10 mA for safety.

Comment: 1.8 is good and indicates high efficacy and lower ESR than typ. actual Vth is less than 1.8 (which is an asymptotic value only. )  20mA is still safe unless you have an unregulated supply, then 10mA is wise